# HTML code in a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is a good practice to put html code in a MySql database?. To be more specific, I have a blog. I have a separated field in the database for each part: the title of the page (metadata), the description, the title of the post, the body of the post... The field of the body sometimes needs html or a way to distinguish the subtitles, the img or the videos and their captions that are between the text of the body of each post.

I am the only one that puts content in that database. So I suppose I do not need to clean any html.

- Is a good practice to put html code in a MySql database?
- If html is not a good practice, how to distinguish YouTube videos and caption that are between the text of the body of the post

Comment: You can use a markdown library. See: http://parsedown.org/

Comment: Why do I have a negative point? what is wrong with that question?

Comment: *I am the only one that puts content in that database. So I suppose I do not need to clean any html.* Sorry but this is fundamentally the wrong attitude to take. What if your account gets compromised? What can your code do as **damage limitation** when the brown stuff hits the fan? ***Always*** clean any database input regardless of source. *Never* trust your source, what if you're adding things and your computer is compromised and malware is appending data to your textarea fields upon submission?

Comment: Ok, good point. Thank you, Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not suggest storing HTML in your database because it requires too many cleanups to prevent storing malicious Javascript code in your database. So instead, you can use a PHP markdown library to nicely format your messages with a human intuitive format, which will be parsed into HTML when you display it, similar to Stackoverflow or Github.

See: http://parsedown.org/

Example:

```
1. List 1
2. List 2
```

Translates to:

```
<ol>
   <li>List 1</li>
   <li>List 1</li>
</ol>
```

---

As for the Youtube embedding mentioned in the comment, there is a simple solution with markdown: Add an extra markdown rule!

You can make the markdown syntax clean like this: `@[Alt text] (YouTube-code)`

Which would translate to the following HTML:

```
<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{YouTube-code }}?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>{{ Alt text }}</iframe>
```

Check out the source of this information on how to implement this markdown syntax for YT:

https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/issues/130

Comment: Ok, I can use markdown. But the question is how to store the body of the post if there are videos between the text. I think Markdown does not have a solution for YouTube videos and their caption

Comment: You can inject further markdown rules to the library if you like and even Youtube videos be read via markdown. Something like `@[Alt text] (YouTube-code)` could translate to `<iframe class="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{YouTube-code }}?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>{{ Alt text }}</iframe>`. Check out this link: https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/issues/130

Answer (score 2):

Question: is it good practice to store HTML code in a MySQL database?

Answer: No. It is not.

You should never show HTML code from a database. Always assume that there could be malicious HTML code in the database (XSS), even if you are the only one with access to it. Never show this HTML.

Use another library or format that converts tags to HTML. It allows you to store subtitles like this: `[subtitle]This Subtitle[/subtitle]` and convert those tags later to (example) `<h2>This Subtitle</h2>`.

This way, when you would ever want to change the subtitles from `<h2>` to `<h3>`, you only have to do this on 1 place instead of changing every blogpost you ever made.

Another example would be youtube videos: assume you store the HTML. Tomorrow, YouTube changes its player and you have to change every YouTube video you ever posted. If you would've used `[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/whatevervide[/youtube]`, that means you only have to change the HTML code once.

Comment: your answer does well for stating using an interface for clarity of changes, but you make no actual mention of the percieved insecurities of storing HTML code.

Comment: I think I mentioned that: "You should never show HTML code from a database. Always assume that there could be malicious HTML code in the database (XSS), even if you are the only one with access to it. Never show this HTML."

Comment: HTML code is not automatically bad, and as long as the code is properly checked and validated before saving there is little reason not to store HTML code *just because it's HTML*. You don't mention why it would be bad to store raw (cleaned) HTML code?

Comment: You shouldn't alter content when you store it in your database. Either save it unchanged (and as a prepared statement), or don't save it at all (and show an error). You should escape the HTML when you show the data in a HTML page, not when you insert it in a database.

Comment: I think that's somewhat more a matter of opinion; I would happily clean `<script>` tags and such-like from a string before storing, but yes, processing upon output is the preferred point to process string contents

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of opinion. There is no harm **storing** malicious HTML in your database. The harm is in **showing** malicious HTML from the database. Even if you escape HTML when inputting in your database, which you shouldn't, you still have to escape it (again) when showing it. Never assume that your database is safe.

Answer (score 0):

As far as blog concern it is good if you add blog in to database. Because there is many html tag which we need to implement on different different places so we can't do that static or by code.

For best way to store body in to the database :-
Try using htmlspecialchars() on the string to put into the DB, and then, when pulling it back out, use htmlspecialchars_decode()

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "right" way.

Storing HTML in the database is no problem at all. SO stores both the Markdown and the rendered HTML in the database. Serving the HTML is faster to render the page because the Markdown is already parsed. If a post is edited, the Markdown will be parsed to HTML again and stored in the database.

Another approach is to only save the Markdown (or HTML). Since only you will create the pages it is not necessary to check the input for malicious code. If you still want to do this, I would advise checking out [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which works like a charm.